# SSRS 2012 - my scatter chart isn't showing all data points

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a scatter chart in SSRS (SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2010) that is producing the following:

[image: one chart]

There are eleven data points on there, however the result set I am using has 61 rows (a 'Completed Date' of datetime and a 'Days Late' integer whose values go from circa -75 to 75.

How can I tell SSRS to show every data point in my chart?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found a previous article that had a similar issue here: [Multiple Y values for a single X in SSRS line\scatter chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659807/multiple-y-values-for-a-single-x-in-ssrs-line-scatter-chart?rq=1)

I went to my database and found that I had 400 records, and was displaying about 130. One example I found was that I had multiple values on the "Y" axis that were duplicate (in my case I had 5 values that the Y axis was 41). Until I changed 41 to 41.1 for one value, I couldn't get more than one of the values to display on the screen on the Y axis 41 line. Clearing up those data values to include decimal points helped me solve this.